# Problems with python postgis polygon

Tags: python, postgis

I have a problem with the examples in the book "*Python Geospatial Development*". I can't write to the PostgreSQL database polygons from TM_WORLD_BORDERS (Chapter 7, page 202 in book). Code:

```
src_file = os.path.join('TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')

shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open(src_file)
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)


for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    name = feature.GetField('NAME').decode('Latin-1')
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()

    wkt = geometry.ExportToWkt()

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO countries (name, outline) '+
                   'VALUES (%s, ST_PolygonFromText(%s, 4326))' +
                   '', (name.encode('utf8'), wkt))

    connection.commit()
```

Only 30 out of 246 polygons are written. But the geometry.IsValid() function shows that 242 country polygons are valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think it blows up on the first invalid one, you need to use the isvalid check as you go

Comment: I think that is not the case. In my view the problem as a function of ST_PolygonFromText () which in most cases, returns Null instead of the binary representation of the countrie-polygons. But this polygons are valid